# Run Selected Pipeline Batches Command as Admin User

Tags: data-exchange-framework, scheduled-tasks, commands

I have a pipeline batch which sync external data into Sitecore items.

I extend **RunPipelineBatchCommand** to run as admin user, default is running as Context.User:

```
 protected override User GetRunAsUser()
    {
           return User.FromName(domainName + @"\" + myadminuser, true);
    }
```

If I run manually the pipeline batch is running perfectly.

I have a "**Run Selected Pipeline Batches Command**" which is used by a Scheduler Task to run daily. 
The problem is the pipeline batch is running like sitecore/anonymous user and not **myadminuser** .

How can I set **Run Selected Pipeline Batches Command** to be trigger as admin user and not anonymous user.

Comment: Hi Vlad received any update for this, or any workaround?
I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @BhaveshRana my answer below might be interesting for you.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because the `Run Selected Pipeline Batches Command` uses different code to run a Pipeline Batch. I prepared a custom implementation of schedule command (unfortunately the existing command was not really override-friendly, so code looks not nice, but I assume it will work):

```
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Contexts;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Local.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Models;
using Sitecore.DataExchange.Runners;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Jobs;
using Sitecore.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class CustomRunSelectedPipelineBatches : Sitecore.DataExchange.Local.Tasks.RunSelectedPipelineBatches
    {

        protected override void RunPipelineBatches(
            CommandItem command,
            IEnumerable<ID> ids,
            Sitecore.DataExchange.Local.Tasks.MultiplePipelineSettings settings)
        {
            IDictionary<ID, PipelineBatch> pipelineBatches = GetPipelineBatches(command, ids);
            if (!ArePipelineBatchesValidToRun(command, pipelineBatches.Values))
            {
                Log.Error(string.Format("At least one pipeline batch assigned to command {0} is not valid to run. None of the pipeline batches will be run, per settings on the command.", (object)command.ID, (object)command.Database.Name), (object)this);
            }
            else
            {
                IPipelineBatchRunner<Job> pipelineBatchRunner = GetPipelineBatchRunner(command);
                if (pipelineBatchRunner == null)
                {
                    Log.Error(string.Format("No pipeline batch runner is available for command {0}.", command.ID), this);
                }
                else
                {
                    using (new Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher(GetUser()))
                    {
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<ID, PipelineBatch> keyValuePair in pipelineBatches)
                        {
                            PipelineBatchContext pipelineBatchContext =
                                this.GetPipelineBatchContext(keyValuePair.Value);
                            if (!pipelineBatchRunner.Run(keyValuePair.Value, pipelineBatchContext) &&
                                !settings.ContinueOnError)
                            {
                                Log.Info(
                                    string.Format(
                                        "An error occured when command {0} tried to run the pipeline batch {1}. No additional pipeline batches will be run, per settings on the command.",
                                        (object) command.ID, (object) keyValuePair.Key), (object) this);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void RunPipelineBatchesAsync(
            CommandItem command,
            IEnumerable<ID> ids,
            Sitecore.DataExchange.Local.Tasks.MultiplePipelineSettings settings)
        {
            IDictionary<ID, PipelineBatch> pipelineBatches = this.GetPipelineBatches(command, ids);
            if (!ArePipelineBatchesValidToRun(command, pipelineBatches.Values))
            {
                Log.Error(string.Format("At least one pipeline batch assigned to command {0} is not valid to run. None of the pipeline batches will be run, per settings on the command.", (object)command.ID, (object)command.Database.Name), (object)this);
            }
            else
            {
                IPipelineBatchRunner<Job> pipelineBatchRunner = GetPipelineBatchRunner(command);
                if (pipelineBatchRunner == null)
                {
                    Log.Error(string.Format("No pipeline batch runner is available for command {0}.", command.ID), this);
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (PipelineBatch pipelineBatch in pipelineBatches.Values)
                    {
                        object[] objArray = new object[3]
                        {
                            pipelineBatchRunner,
                            GetUser(),
                            pipelineBatch
                        };
                        JobOptions jobOptions = new JobOptions(pipelineBatch.Name, "Data Exchange", Sitecore.Context.Site.Name, (object)this, "CustomRunPipelineBatchAsJob", objArray);
                        pipelineBatchRunner.CurrentProcesses[pipelineBatch.Identifier] = JobManager.Start(jobOptions);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void CustomRunPipelineBatchAsJob(IPipelineBatchRunner<Job> runner, Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User currentUser, PipelineBatch pipelineBatch)
        {
            if (runner == null || pipelineBatch == null)
                return;
            using (new Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher(currentUser))
            {
                PipelineBatchContext pipelineBatchContext = this.GetPipelineBatchContext(pipelineBatch);
                runner.Run(pipelineBatch, pipelineBatchContext);
            }

        }

        private IPipelineBatchRunner<Job> GetPipelineBatchRunner(
            CommandItem command)
        {
            if (command == null)
                return null;
            BaseRunMultiplePipelineBatchesCommandItem innerItem = (BaseRunMultiplePipelineBatchesCommandItem)command.InnerItem;
            if (innerItem == null)
            {
                Log.Error(string.Format("The command {0} cannot run pipeline batches.", command.ID), this);
                return null;
            }
            Type pipelineBatchRunnerType = innerItem.PipelineBatchRunnerType;
            if (!(pipelineBatchRunnerType == null))
                return Activator.CreateInstance(pipelineBatchRunnerType) as IPipelineBatchRunner<Job>;
            Log.Error(string.Format("The command {0} does not have a valid pipeline batch runner type specified.", command.ID), this);
            return null;
        }

        private bool ArePipelineBatchesValidToRun(
            CommandItem command,
            IEnumerable<PipelineBatch> pipelineBatches)
        {
            foreach (PipelineBatch pipelineBatch in pipelineBatches)
            {
                if (pipelineBatch == null)
                    return false;
                IPipelineBatchRunner<Job> pipelineBatchRunner = GetPipelineBatchRunner(command);
                if (pipelineBatchRunner == null)
                    return false;
                if (pipelineBatchRunner.IsRunning(pipelineBatch.Identifier))
                {
                    Log.Error(string.Format("At least one pipeline batch assigned to command {0} is already running.", (object)command.ID, (object)command.Database.Name), (object)this);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        private IDictionary<ID, PipelineBatch> GetPipelineBatches(
            CommandItem command,
            IEnumerable<ID> ids)
        {
            Dictionary<ID, PipelineBatch> dictionary = new Dictionary<ID, PipelineBatch>();
            Sitecore.DataExchange.IConverter<Item, PipelineBatch> converter = this.Converter;
            if (converter == null)
            {
                Log.Error(string.Format("No converter is assigned to convert items to pipeline batch objects. (command: {0}, database: {1})", (object)command.ID, (object)command.Database.Name), (object)this);
                return (IDictionary<ID, PipelineBatch>)dictionary;
            }
            foreach (ID id in ids)
            {
                Item source = command.Database.GetItem(id);
                if (source == null)
                {
                    Log.Error(string.Format("Item not found in the database. (command: {0}, database: {1}, id: {2})", (object)command.ID, (object)command.Database.Name, (object)id), (object)this);
                }
                else
                {
                    Sitecore.DataExchange.ConvertResult<PipelineBatch> convertResult = converter.Convert(source);
                    if (convertResult.WasConverted)
                    {
                        PipelineBatch convertedValue = convertResult.ConvertedValue;
                        if (convertedValue == null)
                            Log.Error(string.Format("Item could not be converted to a pipeline batch. (command: {0}, database: {1}, id: {2})", (object)command.ID, (object)command.Database.Name, (object)id), (object)this);
                        else
                            dictionary.Add(id, convertedValue);
                    }
                }
            }
            return (IDictionary<ID, PipelineBatch>)dictionary;
        }


        protected virtual Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User GetUser()
        {
            return Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(domainName + @"\" + myadminuser, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Put it into your solution build and set according namespace for the schedule command.